# Enclose selected text in an environment in Kile

Tags: environments, kile

Let us say that I have some text and I want to enclose the selected text in an environment of my choice and have the text indent itself inside the environment. So, I shall select the text, and press some key. This results in the following.

1. A line is added to the top and bottom of the selected text, with `\begin{}` and `\end{}`.
2. The cursor is placed inside the curly brackets in `\begin{^}`. `^` denotes the position of the cursor. Whatever I type here gets copied in `\end{}` as well. Nothing outside the curly brackets gets copied.
3. The selected text gets an indent inside the environment.

Perhaps a shortcut can be set for commonly used environments.

Is this possible to achieve in Kile?